# Enter and Exit menu using enum and switch sfml

Tags: c++, game-engine, sfml

In my game right now I am trying to make a menu you can access when you press 'q', but currently I am having some issues. I think it switches to the `CompScreen` view and then back to the `currentroom` view quickly, I may be wrong. I am getting the cout CompMenu, HELP, and hello readings so I know it is running through the programs, but when I press q I remain in the same spot, nothing happening.

EventManager.h

```
#ifndef EventManager_h
#define EventManager_h


#endif /* EventManager_h */


int windowWidth = 5000;//width of window
int windowHeight = 5000;//height of window
sf::View leveltwo(sf::FloatRect(x, y, 5000, 5000));
sf::View start(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 2500, 1500));
sf::View ComputerScreen(sf::FloatRect(50000, 50000, 5000, 5000));
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight ), "Awesome Game" );
Character player("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/Sprites/Player.png");

bool InMenu = false;

enum Levels{
    StartRoom, LevelTwo
};
Levels room = StartRoom;
int currentroom;
void WhatRoom(int TheLevel){

    switch (room){
        case StartRoom:
            currentroom = 1;
            window.setView(start);
            if (TheLevel == 2){
                room = LevelTwo;
            }
            break;
        case LevelTwo:
            currentroom = 2;
            window.setView(leveltwo);
            break;



    }
};


enum States{
    compmenu, mainmenu, NoMenu
};
States menu = NoMenu;

void CompMenu(){
    window.setView(ComputerScreen);
    cout << "HELP";
    InMenu = true;

}
void WhatMenu(int TheMenu){
    switch (menu){
        case compmenu:
            cout << "CompMenu";
            CompMenu();
            break;
        case mainmenu:
            break;
        case NoMenu:
            if (TheMenu == 2){
                menu = compmenu;
            }
            break;
            if (TheMenu == 3){
                menu = mainmenu;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

main.cpp (inside int main)

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q) and InMenu == false){
            WhatMenu(2);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q) and InMenu == true){
            InMenu = false;
            WhatRoom(currentroom);
            cout << "hello";
        }
```

If you have any questions or need to see more of the code let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed `else` after first `if` block so it may be executed immediately because `InMenu` may be changed to `true` at that point:

```
else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q) and InMenu == true){
```

Also you should handle the situation when key is pressed for a long time (to react only when it enters pressed state) and get rid of all the global variables because they are already creating quite a mess.